# Sort a column containing strings representing software versions in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I have a dataframe where one of the columns is a string with a software name and different versions. When trying to sort by this column the ordering is not respecting the versioning.

The column to sort has a format of this kind

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'versions': ['cd-2.8.10', 'cd-3.10.3', 'cd-3.3.1', 'cd-3.10.10', 'cd-3.12.0', 'ab-5.2.1', 'cd-3.1.3', 'cd-3.5.2', 'ab-3.0.2', 'cd-3.10.1', 'cd-3.20.1', 'cd-3.11.4']})
>>> df
      versions
0    cd-2.8.10
1    cd-3.10.3
2     cd-3.3.1
3   cd-3.10.10
4    cd-3.12.0
5     ab-5.2.1
6     cd-3.1.3
7     cd-3.5.2
8     ab-3.0.2
9    cd-3.10.1
10   cd-3.20.1
11   cd-3.11.4
```

when using `sort_values()` the string part with characters before the dash is perfectly sorted alphabetically, but for a given software the version number sorting is wrong by taking `3.10.1` as smaller to `3.3.1`, or `3.10.10` as smaller than `3.10.3`

```
>>> df.sort_values('versions')
      versions
8     ab-3.0.2
5     ab-5.2.1
0    cd-2.8.10
6     cd-3.1.3
9    cd-3.10.1
3   cd-3.10.10
1    cd-3.10.3
11   cd-3.11.4
4    cd-3.12.0
10   cd-3.20.1
2     cd-3.3.1
7     cd-3.5.2
```

I would like to get the correct version ordering as

```
      versions
8     ab-3.0.2
5     ab-5.2.1
0    cd-2.8.10
6     cd-3.1.3
2     cd-3.3.1
7     cd-3.5.2
9    cd-3.10.1
1    cd-3.10.3
3   cd-3.10.10
11   cd-3.11.4
4    cd-3.12.0
10   cd-3.20.1
```

Comment: Would it be possible here to use a method similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43787091/sort-values-with-key-in-python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a complicated issue because pandas does not directly support natural sorting. Thankfully, using the [`natsort`](https://natsort.readthedocs.io/en/master/) module, this should be easy and also handle most version formats.

```
from natsort import natsorted
df.iloc[natsorted(df.index, key=lambda x: df.loc[x, 'versions'])]

      versions
8     ab-3.0.2
5     ab-5.2.1
0    cd-2.8.10
6     cd-3.1.3
2     cd-3.3.1
7     cd-3.5.2
9    cd-3.10.1
1    cd-3.10.3
3   cd-3.10.10
11   cd-3.11.4
4    cd-3.12.0
10   cd-3.20.1
```

Here's another way of sorting this data (it is slightly faster because we avoid the lambda),

```
d = df.versions.to_dict()
df.iloc[natsorted(d, key=d.get)]

      versions
8     ab-3.0.2
5     ab-5.2.1
0    cd-2.8.10
6     cd-3.1.3
2     cd-3.3.1
7     cd-3.5.2
9    cd-3.10.1
1    cd-3.10.3
3   cd-3.10.10
11   cd-3.11.4
4    cd-3.12.0
10   cd-3.20.1
```