# How to change row order like A1, A10, A11, ..., A2 to A1, A2, ..., A10, A11 in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

When I import my data files from designated folder, Pandas dataframe automatically sort the row order like  A1, A10, A11, ..., A2, but I wanna make it like A1, A2, ..., A10, A11 so A2 comes before A10, A11.

Do you know how to change the row order ? The row order of all columns should change not just a certain column that contains  A1, A10, A11, ..., A2. So, for instance, the row order of column 'ID' and 'Identifier' should change according to 'Loc' Column.
Also, The actual data is longer with more letters until Z.

example code is:

```
data = {'ID':['S1', 'S1', 'S1' ,'S1'  ,'S2' ,'S3' ,'S3', 'S4', 'Negative', 'Positive', 'Negative',
             'S1', 'S1' ,'S2' ,'S2' ,'S2' ,'S3' ,'S4', 'S4', 'Positive', 'Positive', 'Negative'], 
   'Loc':['A1', 'A10', 'A11' ,'A2' ,'A3' ,'A4' ,'A5', 'A6', 'A7', 'A8', 'A9',
               'B1', 'B10', 'B11' ,'B2' ,'B3' ,'B4' ,'B5' ,'B6', 'B7', 'B8', 'B9'],
   'Identifier' :['asd01', 'asd02', 'asd04', 'asd05', 'asd06', 'asd07', 'asd08', 'asd09'
             ,'asd10' ,'asd11' ,'asd13' ,'asd14' ,'asd15', 'asd16', 'asd17', 'asd18',
             'asd19', 'asd20', 'asd21', 'asd22', 'asd23', 'asd24']}
```

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sort\_values() with key in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43787091/sort-values-with-key-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there might be better ways to do this, but this can be used as a work around for now;
divide the column you want to sort to Char and Int, then sort by values:

```
df['letter'] = df.Loc.apply(lambda x: x[0])
df['number'] = df.Loc.apply(lambda x: int(x[1:]))
df = df.sort_values(by=['letter', 'number'])
```

Then you can drop the created columns.
Note that if your 'Loc' has instances with more than one character, you'll need other means of separating the letter from the number, regex maybe.